# How Do I Enable Blue Lines in Excel's Page Break Preview

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

When in Page Break Preview there are no blue lines to adjust. Where do I find the blue lines or how can I get them back?

I haven't tried anything because I don't even know where to begin. I've been trying to google but the only information that comes up is how to create, delete page breaks. I know how to adjust page breaks but its a little impossible and frustrating to do without the blue lines.

[image]

Comment: Please upload a screenshot.

Comment: Please use the built-in image upload tool to put the screenshot in your original post instead of linking to external files.

Comment: Also, are you sure there aren't blue lines around the edge of the print area? If the entire document is going to print on a single sheet, there will still be thick blue lines around the exterior border.

Comment: @EngineerToast Sorry I didn't know how to put the screenshot in but my problem has been solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the same blue lines that I think you are (solid blue around the outside and dotted blue on the interior)...those are references to show how the pages will print.  You can also adjust those with your mouse (hover over the line and a double sided arrow will appear or you can highlight the print range you want and go to Page Layout => Page Setup => Print Area.  As for how to get them back, try redefining your print area.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked...I got back my blue lines. Appreciate the help